# Grails 4: Save doesn't work in service method with prefix 'set'

Tags: grails, grails-orm

Using Grails 4.0.11 and OpenJDK 11, I came across a very strange behaviour that I was able to extract to a standalone project where I made sure it hasn't to do with plugins:

Given is a controller:

```
def updateOrder() { 
  def order = Order.get(params.id)
  def result = shopService.setOrderPrintFileChecked(order)
  redirect(action: "detailOrder", id: order.id)
}
```

and the service

```
@Transactional
class ShopService {
    def setOrderPrintFileChecked(Order order) {
        order.printFileChecked = new Date()
        println("Validate: " + order.validate())
        println("Errors: " + order.errors)
        println("Dirty: " + order.isDirty())
        def r = order.save(failOnError: true)
        println("Result: " + r.printFileChecked)
        return true
    }
}
```

this does not save me the value to the database (tried MySQL+H2 default db).
If displays:

```
Validate: true
Errors: org.grails.datastore.mapping.validation.ValidationErrors: 0 errors
Dirty: true
Result: Sun Nov 21 15:58:17 CET 2021
```

**if I change the method of ShopService from setOrderPrintFileChecked() to setorderPrintFileChecked() or even test()** it works and the value is beeing saved correctly.**

it seems that the prefix + camelCase "setXyz" has a different behaviour. I'd like to know what it is and how to fix/prevent this case. Can provide full demo-application with the behaviour.

** Update**
This is de de-compiled service class with a non-setter-name:

```
    public Object updateMyValue(final Order order) {
        final Reference order2 = new Reference((Object)order);
        final CustomizableRollbackTransactionAttribute $transactionAttribute = new CustomizableRollbackTransactionAttribute();
        $transactionAttribute.setName("ch.pacdesigner.ShopService.updateMyValue");
        final GrailsTransactionTemplate $transactionTemplate = new GrailsTransactionTemplate(this.getTransactionManager(), $transactionAttribute);
        return $transactionTemplate.execute((Closure)new ShopService._updateMyValue_closure1((Object)this, (Object)this, order2));
    }
```

this is the compiled method

```
    public Object setOrderPrintFileChecked(final Order order) {
        final CallSite[] $getCallSiteArray = $getCallSiteArray();
        ScriptBytecodeAdapter.setGroovyObjectProperty($getCallSiteArray[0].callConstructor((Object)Date.class), (Class)ShopService.class, (GroovyObject)order, (String)"printFileChecked");
        $getCallSiteArray[1].call((Object)order, (Object)ScriptBytecodeAdapter.createMap(new Object[] { "failOnError", true }));
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: I've just bumped into a similar issue, so I'm guessing this has to do with Grails modifying setters to handle the dirty checking. Google "grails setter dirty" if you want to examine it further. I would try order.setPrintFileChecked(new Date()) and see if that works in all examples.

Comment: Does the decompiled "setOrderPrintFileChecked" method have transaction management instructions in it?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown I tried it with different method names and the method is always the same, named 'setOrderPrintFileChecked' or 'holaSullivan'. If I add '@Transactional' to the method head, it works with 'setOrderPrintFileChecked' - but if I add it to the service, it should be valid for any methods. If I add "withTransaction" block, it works, too. But that's not the idea of DRY IMHO.

Comment: " I tried it with different method names and the method is always the same" - Does the decompiled instructions in the `setOrderPrintFileChecked` have transaction management logic in it?

Comment: You have not shown enough code to say for sure but it looks like you are retrieving the entity from the database before starting a transaction.  Is that the case?

Comment: @JeffScottBrown I added the two codes, I was wrong. The method with a "non-setter-name" has a different line that the other one hasn't. How comes?

Comment: "How comes?" - I expect it is because the setter isn't being configured with tx management.  I do not know why that would be and if it is intentional, but the reason I asked is I suspected it wasn't transactional, and the code you have added has confirmed that.

Comment: https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/blob/c69add974963a3a1fcab27271d7ab4fa7c1faee2/grails-datastore-gorm/src/main/groovy/org/grails/datastore/gorm/transform/AbstractMethodDecoratingTransformation.groovy#L113 is likely relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Jeff Scott Brown stated, this behaviour is due to:
https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/blob/c69add974963a3a1fcab27271d7ab4fa7c1faee2/grails-datastore-gorm/src/main/groovy/org/grails/datastore/gorm/transform/AbstractMethodDecoratingTransformation.groovy#L113